# LaTeX Table error- Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

Tags: errors, multicolumn

What is the problem in the following table code?

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{Comparative Results}
\label{Results}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|ccc|ccc|ccc|ccc|}
\hline
\textbf{M1 vs.$} & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\textbf{5fold}} & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\textbf{10fold}} \\\cline{2-13} & &  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Err1}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Err2}} &  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Err1}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Err2}} \\\cline{2-13} & & \textbf{C1} & \textbf{C2} & \textbf{C3} & \textbf{C1} & \textbf{C2} & \textbf{C3} & \textbf{C1} & \textbf{C2} & \textbf{C3} & \textbf{C1} & \textbf{C2} & \textbf{C3} \\ \hline
M2 & 13 & 7 & 0 & 15 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 20 & 0 & 0 & 20 & 0    \\
M3 & 11 & 3 & 6 & 12 & 3 & 5 & 3 & 13 & 4 & 0 & 16 & 4    \\
M4 & 10 & 10 & 0 & 10 & 10 & 0 & 4 & 16 & 0 & 0 & 20 & 0    \\    \hline
Total & 34 & 20 & 6 & 37 & 18 & 5    & 7 &    49 & 4    & 0 &    56 & 4    \\    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Right after each of the two `\cline{2-13} ` commands, there are two `&`. You probably wanted to use just one `&` there.

Answer (score 6):

1. You had a `$` symbol that was not "escaped" (`\$`).
2. You **define 13 columns** (`\begin{tabular}{|c|ccc|ccc|ccc|ccc|}`) but some of your rows have **more than 13 columns**.
3. I commented (`%`) the problematic rows so that you can see that the code compiles now.
4. I am too lazy right now to exactly find the summation mistake :).
5. In general, I would recommend that you start with a generic table in which you make it very obvious how many columns you have, see the example. This way you can create the structure and can easily spot mistakes (counting columns).

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Comparative Results}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|ccc|ccc|ccc|ccc|}
\hline
\textbf{M1 vs.\$} & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\textbf{5fold}} & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\textbf{10fold}} \\\cline{2-13} 
%& &  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Err1}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Err2}} &  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Err1}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Err2}} \\\cline{2-13} 
%& & \textbf{C1} & \textbf{C2} & \textbf{C3} & \textbf{C1} & \textbf{C2} & \textbf{C3} & \textbf{C1} & \textbf{C2} & \textbf{C3} & \textbf{C1} & \textbf{C2} & \textbf{C3} \\ \hline
M2 & 13 & 7 & 0 & 15 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 20 & 0 & 0 & 20 & 0  \\  
M3 & 11 & 3 & 6 & 12 & 3 & 5 & 3 & 13 & 4 & 0 & 16 & 4  \\  
M4 & 10 & 10 & 0 & 10 & 10 & 0 & 4 & 16 & 0 & 0 & 20 & 0   \\  \hline
Total & 34 & 20 & 6 & 37 & 18 & 5   & 7 &   49 & 4  & 0 &   56 & 4  \\  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{Comparative Results}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|ccc|ccc|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c}{\textbf{C1 and C2}} & C3 & \textbf{C4} & \textbf{C5} & \textbf{C6}\\\hline
C1 & C2 & C3 & C4 & C5 & C6\\
C1 & C2 & C3 & C4 & C5 & C6\\
C1 & C2 & C3 & C4 & C5 & C6\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Errors in your table code fragment are already dealt with in [leandriis's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603288/latex-table-error-extra-alignment-tab-has-been-changed-to-cr#comment1513172_603288) and [Dr. Manuel Kuehner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603288/latex-table-error-extra-alignment-tab-has-been-changed-to-cr/603293#603293) (+1). Here is only a suggestion, how can you write your table with the new LaTeX 3 table package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
 colspec = {|c| *{4}{*{3}{c}|} },
row{1-3} = {font=\bfseries},
            }
    \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{M1 vs. \$} 
    & \multicolumn{6}{c}{5fold} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{10fold}            \\
    \cline{2-13}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Err1}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Err2}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Err1}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Err2}              \\
    \cline{2-13} 
    & C1 & C2 & C3 &    C1 & C2 & C3 &  C1 & C2 & C3 &  C1 & C2 & C3    \\ 
    \hline
M2  & 13 &  7 &  0 &    15 &  5 &  0 &   0 & 20 &  0 &   0 & 20 &  0    \\
M3  & 11 &  3 &  6 &    12 &  3 &  5 &   3 & 13 &  4 &   0 & 16 &  4    \\
M4  & 10 & 10 &  0 &    10 & 10 &  0 &   4 & 16 &  0 &   0 & 20 &  0    \\  
        \hline
Total 
    & 34 & 20 &  6 &    37 & 18 &  5 &   7 & 49 &  4 &   0 & 56 &  4    \\  
    \hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

I try to use `\NewTableCommand` for defining shortness for the `\multicolumn` command. Unfortunately the suggestion as proposed by the author of the `tabularray` package doesn't work yet as expected. Hopefully with the new package release this will be solved. So far let us stick with the first version of this answer.

**Edit (1):**
With recent `tabularray` (from 2022A further) above code doesn't work anymore. Command `multicolumn` is not supported anymore, instead of it now should be used `\SetCell` on a way as shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
 colspec = {|c| *{4}{*{3}{c}|} },
row{1-3} = {font=\bfseries},
            }
    \hline
\SetCell[r=3]{c}    M1 vs. \$ 
    & \SetCell[c=6]{c}  5fold   
        &   &   &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=6]{c}  10fold              
                                &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    \hline
    & \SetCell[c=6]{c}  Err1    
        &   &   &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=6]{c}  Err2 
                                &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    \hline
    & C1 & C2 & C3 &    C1 & C2 & C3 &  C1 & C2 & C3 &  C1 & C2 & C3    \\
    \hline
M2  & 13 &  7 &  0 &    15 &  5 &  0 &   0 & 20 &  0 &   0 & 20 &  0    \\
M3  & 11 &  3 &  6 &    12 &  3 &  5 &   3 & 13 &  4 &   0 & 16 &  4    \\
M4  & 10 & 10 &  0 &    10 & 10 &  0 &   4 & 16 &  0 &   0 & 20 &  0    \\
    \hline
Total
    & 34 & 20 &  6 &    37 & 18 &  5 &   7 & 49 &  4 &   0 & 56 &  4    \\
    \hline
\end{tblr}
```

Result is the sam ase before.

Shortness for `multicolum` now has not special sence , but if someone like to use it, it can be defined for example as `\NewTableCommand\SCC[1]{\SetCell[c=#1]{c}}` and than use as `\SCC{6}

**Edit (2):**
With version 2022B is available library `{functional}` by which you can make calculation of values in the last row in table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{functional}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\IgnoreSpacesOn
\prgNewFunction \funcSum {} {
\intStepOneInline {2} {\arabic{colcount}} { % calculation from column 2 further
\intZero \lTmpaInt
\intStepOneInline {4} {\arabic{rowcount}-1} {% calculation from row further
\intAdd \lTmpaInt {\cellGetText {####1} {##1}}
}
\cellSetText {\expWhole{\arabic{rowcount}}} {##1} {\intUse\lTmpaInt}
}
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff
%
\begin{tblr}{
 colspec = {|c| *{4}{*{3}{c}|} }, 
row{1-3} = {font=\bfseries},
process=\funcSum,
            }
    \hline
\SetCell[r=3]{c}    M1 vs. \$ 
    & \SetCell[c=6]{c}  5fold   
        &   &   &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=6]{c}  10fold              
                                &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    \hline
    & \SetCell[c=6]{c}  Err1    
        &   &   &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=6]{c}  Err2 
                                &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    \hline
    & C1 & C2 & C3 &    C1 & C2 & C3 &  C1 & C2 & C3 &  C1 & C2 & C3    \\
    \hline
M2  & 13 &  7 &  0 &    15 &  5 &  0 &   0 & 20 &  0 &   0 & 20 &  0    \\
M3  & 11 &  3 &  6 &    12 &  3 &  5 &   3 & 13 &  4 &   0 & 16 &  4    \\
M4  & 10 & 10 &  0 &    10 & 10 &  0 &   4 & 16 &  0 &   0 & 20 &  0    \\
    \hline
Total
    &    &    &    &       &    &    &     &    &    &     &    &       \\
    \hline
\end{tblr}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: From your answer I can learn a thing or two :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, unfortunately it after editing doesn't work as package author advertise (or I wrongly use his instruction).  Correct result you will obtain, if you will replace `\mcc[,,,]{<text>}` with `\multicolumn{...}{c}{<text>}`. See my question in given link.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|ccc|ccc|ccc|ccc|}[cell-space-limits=2pt]
\Hline
\RowStyle[nb-rows=3]{\bfseries}
\Block{3-1}{M1 vs. \$} & \Block{1-6}{5fold}&&&&&& \Block{1-6}{10fold} \\
\Hline
& \Block{1-3}{Err1} &&& \Block{1-3}{Err1} &&& \Block{1-3}{Err1} &&& \Block{1-3}{Err2} \\
\Hline
    & C1 & C2 & C3 & C1 & C2 & C3 & C1 & C2 & C3 & C1 & C2 & C3    \\ 
\Hline
M2  & 13 &  7 &  0 &    15 &  5 &  0 &   0 & 20 &  0 &   0 & 20 &  0    \\
M3  & 11 &  3 &  6 &    12 &  3 &  5 &   3 & 13 &  4 &   0 & 16 &  4    \\
M4  & 10 & 10 &  0 &    10 & 10 &  0 &   4 & 16 &  0 &   0 & 20 &  0    \\  
\Hline
Total 
    & 34 & 20 &  6 &    37 & 18 &  5 &   7 & 49 &  4 &   0 & 56 &  4    \\  
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do that table with OpTeX

```
\def\msc{\mspan3[c|]}
\table{|c|3c|3c|3c|3c|}{\crl
              & \mspan6[c|]{\bf 5fold}           & \mspan6[c|]{\bf 10fold}      \crlp{2-13} 
\bf M1 vs. \$ & \msc{\bf Err1}  & \msc{\bf Err2} & \msc{\bf Err1} & \msc{\bf Err2}\crlp{2-13}
              & C1 & C2 & C3    & C1 & C2 & C3   & C1 & C2 & C3   & C1 & C2 & C3 \crl
M2            & 13 & 7  & 0     & 15 & 5  & 0    & 0  & 20 & 0    & 0 & 20 & 0  \cr
M3            & 11 & 3  & 6     & 12 & 3  & 5    & 3  & 13 & 4    & 0 & 16 & 4  \cr  
M4            & 10 & 10 & 0     & 10 & 10 & 0    & 4  & 16 & 0    & 0 & 20 & 0  \crl
Total         & 34 & 20 & 6     & 37 & 18 & 5    & 7  & 49 & 4    & 0 & 56 & 4  \crl
}
\bye
```