# tabularray and new command for \multicolumn cells

Tags: tables, tabularray

Why new command, defined for example as

```
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
```

doesn't work in `tblr` defined in the `tabularray`˙table on the same way as if it is directly inserted `\multicolumn` cells (or as it works in `tabular` and other "classic" tables' environments). For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tblr}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}


\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
 colspec = {|*{4}{c|} },
hlines
            }
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{abcde}  & \mcc[3]{fghij}    \\
1 & 2 & 3                   & 1 & 2 & 3         \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Do I miss something or `tabularray` so far doesn't support such shortcuts? I use `tabularray` Version 2021K (2021-06-05).

**Edit:**
Solution as is provided autoe of package, doesn't work as (I) expected. The following MWE works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewTableCommand{\mcc}[1][1]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
 hlines, vlines, colspec = {*{6}{c}},
}
 \multicolumn{3}{c|}{abcde}  & \mcc[3]{fghij}  \\
 1 & 2 & 3                   & 1 & 2 & 3     \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Bot use new command ain all instances of `\multicolumn`s doesn't:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewTableCommand{\mcc}[1][1]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
 hlines, vlines, colspec = {*{6}{c}},
}
 \mcc[3]{abcde}  & \mcc[3]{fghij}  \\
 1 & 2 & 3                   & 1 & 2 & 3     \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Do I miss something (again)?

Comment: The package explicitly looks for `\multicolumn` or `\multirow` in order to replace them with its own version.

Comment: @egreg, thank you for info. That is pity. In cases where of complex tables  with extensive use of `\multicolumn` cells showed shorthand are very convenient in table settings.

Comment: @Zarko I think the 'native' command here is `\SetCell`, which I guess one could 'abbreviate'. However, one always has this issue when doing anything verbatim-like, which includes 'read the content and modify'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### New Answer on 2021-07-02

(Also in https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/28)

`Tabularray` package tried its best to support legacy `\multicolumn` and `\multirow` commands by doing some dirty hack. But from this question, it turns out that it's impossible to give full support for these two commands, since these two commands conflict with the design of `tabularray` package.

Therefore I have decided to mark `\multicolumn` and `\multirow` as obsolete, and will remove them in version 2022. To make multicolumn or multirow cells, it's better to use `\SetCell` command in old interfaces, or `cell{i}{j}` in new interfaces.

Also, for backwards compatibility, I will include the last 2021 version of `tabularray` as `tabularray-2021.sty` in future releases for many years. Users could still use it for their old documents by `\usepackage{tabularray-2021}`.

For your question, it's recommended to write it using new interfaces like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
 hlines, vlines, colspec = {*{6}{c}},
 cell{1}{1,4} = {c=3}{c},
}
 abcde &   &   & fghij &   &   \\
 1     & 2 & 3 & 1     & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For another [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603288/latex-table-error-extra-alignment-tab-has-been-changed-to-cr/603301) in the comment, it's recommended to write it using new interfaces like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {|c|*{4}{*{3}{c}|}},
  row{1-3} = {font=\bfseries},
  cell{1}{1} = {r=3}{c},
  cell{1}{2,8} = {c=6}{c},
  cell{2}{2,5,8,11} = {c=3}{c},
}
\hline
  M1 vs. \$  & 5fold &    &    &      &    &    & 10fold &    &    &      &    &    \\
\cline{2-13}
             & Err1  &    &    & Err1 &    &    & Err1   &    &    & Err2 &    &    \\
\cline{2-13} 
             & C1    & C2 & C3 & C1   & C2 & C3 & C1     & C2 & C3 &  C1  & C2 & C3 \\ 
\hline
  M2         & 13    &  7 &  0 & 15   &  5 &  0 & 0      & 20 &  0 &   0  & 20 &  0 \\
  M3         & 11    &  3 &  6 & 12   &  3 &  5 & 3      & 13 &  4 &   0  & 16 &  4 \\
  M4         & 10    & 10 &  0 & 10   & 10 &  0 & 4      & 16 &  0 &   0  & 20 &  0 \\  
\hline
Total        & 34    & 20 &  6 & 37   & 18 &  5 & 7      & 49 &  4 &   0  & 56 &  4 \\  
\hline
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Old Answer on 2021-07-01

From the manual: "All commands which change the specifications of tables **must** be defined with `\NewTableCommand`".

Also `tabularray` package internally treats `\multicolumn` and `\multirow` as commands with only **two** mandatory arguments.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewTableCommand{\mcc}[1][1]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tblr}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
 hlines, vlines, colspec = {*{6}{c}},
}
 \multicolumn{3}{c|}{abcde}  & \mcc[3]{fghij}  \\
 1 & 2 & 3                   & 1 & 2 & 3     \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to use `\NewTableCommand{\mcc}[2][1]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}#2}` such that there are no 'extra' braces?

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation. I will be nice, if in documentation be explained syntax of `\NewTableCommand` and added example for its use in case of defining shorthand for `\multicolumn` .

Comment: @JosephWright It's impossible. Since we need to extract table commands from each cell text according to the argument number of the table commands in `tabularray` package.

Comment: @L.J.R. I'm confused: `\multicolumn` has three arguments, and if we don't remove the braces from the final one, we (at least) force TeX to create an unnecessary group, or in math mode potentially mess up spacing.

Comment: @Zarko There is an example for `NewTableCommand` in the manual. But yes, there are still lots of things to be added to the manual.

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, you are right. The package extracts two arguments of  the `\multicolumn` command and removes a pair of braces after that.

Comment: Just now I discover, that this not work in all cases.  See example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603288/latex-table-error-extra-alignment-tab-has-been-changed-to-cr/603301#603301. Do I wrongly use `\NewTableCommand`?

Comment: Please see edited question.

Comment: @Zarko Seems like a bug in the package. I will look into it later. I have updated the answer and added a better solution for your new question.

Comment: @Zarko I have decided to drop support for `\multicolumn` since it's nearly impossible to fix this problem. Please see my updated answer above.

Comment: Well, is not fair to expect that one package can solve all problems in table settings. I'm quite happy with use `\multirow` and `\multicolumn` on the way similar as is at other tables packages. New syntax is a bit less intuitive  to me yet.

Comment: @L.J.R. Is there a way to define a multi column command (e.g. `\newcommand{\tablesection}[1]{\midrule\midrule\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{#1}} \\ \midrule}`) for `tabularray` without having to count rows? Unfortunately, it's a bit of a pain to keep the row indices consistent with the table content when making repeated edits to the table.

Comment: @danijar Please ask a new question.