# How to combine cells in tabularray

Tags: tables, multicolumn, tabularray

As the title suggests, I'd like to combine two cells to lie within one column.

[image: Table]

The columns 2,3 and 4,5 should go under Kalibrierungswerte and 6,7 and 8,9 should go below Unbekannte Lösung. Now, the `cell{2}{3,5} = {c=2}{c}` part is supposed to achieve just that but it doesn't work. Here's the post I took the aforementioned code part from: [tabularray and new command for \multicolumn cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603349/tabularray-and-new-command-for-multicolumn-cells).
And here's the code example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage[a3paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{talltblr}[
  caption = {Pipettierschema Teilversuch 1 },
  label = {tab:ps1},
  cell{2}{3,5} = {c=2}{c},
]{colspec = {
                        %@{}
                            l c c c c c
                        @{}
                        },
             row{1,2}  = {guard, m, cmd=\hskip0pt},
            }
\toprule
 & Referenz & Kalibrierungswerte & & Unbekannte Lösung & \\ 
        nº & 1 & 2,3 & 4,5 & 6,7 & 8,9 \\ 
\midrule
        Na-Diphosphatpuffer mit Semicarbazid & 1850 & 1850 & 1850 & 1850 & 1850 \\ 
        5 mM NAD+ & 250 & 250 & 250 & 250 & 250 \\ 
        6,25 mM Ethanol & 50 & 50 & 25 & - & - \\ 
        Unbekannte Ethanol-Lösung & - & - & - & 50 & 25 \\ 
        Wasser & 350 & 300 & 325 & 300 & 325 \\ 
        ADH & - & 50 & 50 & 50 & 50 \\ 
        Verdünnung & - & 1:50 & 1:100 & 1:50 & 1:100 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem may be because you put the cell merge instruction `cell{1}{3, 5}={c=2}{c}` (I suppose you've misprinted `cell{2}...`) in the outer specification of the `tblr`, in other words, in square brackets. I just moved it into inner specification, and also added the instruction `hspan=even` to evenly distribute column's width under spanned cells.
Here is the code

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage[a3paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{talltblr}[
  caption = {Pipettierschema Teilversuch 1},
  label = {tab:ps1},
]{         
           cell{1}{3,5} = {c=2}{c},
           hspan=even,
           colspec = {
                        %@{}
                        l c c c c c
                        @{}
                     },
           row{1,2}  = {m, cmd=\hskip0pt},
 }
\toprule
 & Referenz & Kalibrierungswerte & & Unbekannte Lösung & \\ 
        nº & 1 & 2,3 & 4,5 & 6,7 & 8,9 \\ 
\midrule
        Na-Diphosphatpuffer mit Semicarbazid & 1850 & 1850 & 1850 & 1850 & 1850 \\ 
        5 mM NAD+ & 250 & 250 & 250 & 250 & 250 \\ 
        6,25 mM Ethanol & 50 & 50 & 25 & - & - \\ 
        Unbekannte Ethanol-Lösung & - & - & - & 50 & 25 \\ 
        Wasser & 350 & 300 & 325 & 300 & 325 \\ 
        ADH & - & 50 & 50 & 50 & 50 \\ 
        Verdünnung & - & 1:50 & 1:100 & 1:50 & 1:100 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I hope the result is satisfactory

[image: output of the code above]

P.S. In my code `guard` color and `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` have been thrown out as I don't have necessary packages in my TeX installation.